# Image masking with another resizable android

Tags: java, android, image, imageview

I have a requirement where I will be having a background Image and one mask Image. Lets say the background Image is of Motorcycle and the mask will be used to hide the registration number. So the mask will be movable and also resize-able. Finally the combined Image will be generated with background image  and Image mask. How we can achieve this ?

Comment: How do you want the mask to work? To just show the pixels in the background image that have a corresponding mask pixel of some value, or to also apply a filter to the background pixel value?

Comment: It can be a normal red color rectangular box which hides the bike registration number. That's it

Answer (score 0):

```
public Bitmap drawFacesOnBitmap(Context gContext, Bitmap bitmap) {

      android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = bitmap.getConfig();
      // set default bitmap config if none
      if(bitmapConfig == null) {
        bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
      }
      // resource bitmaps are imutable, 
      // so we need to convert it to mutable one
      bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);

      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
      // new antialised Paint
      Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
      // text color - #3D3D3D
      paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

      // draw text to the Canvas center
      Log.d("BITMAP DIMENS****", "bitmapWidth:"+bitmap.getWidth()+" & bitmapHeight:"+bitmap.getHeight());
        android.graphics.Rect r = new android.graphics.Rect();
        r.left = 200;
        r.top = 200;
        r.right = 400;
        r.bottom = 400;
        canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
    return bitmap;
}
```

You can use this code to draw a rectangle on a bitmap. Edit it to meet your needs.